# Moving data entry with filter options

Tags: vba, excel

First off prepare for a long read, I've narrowed down the info as much as I could.

So I am using VBA since a little while now and I've encountered a problem which I can not seem to solve. I'm using a code in VBA to do the following:
Sheet "Two" contains multiple rows of data sets. These data sets can be filtered using dropdown menus in the first row of the sheet. I've set up a macro to check if the necessary data sets are present, which can be checked for by seeing if there is text present in certain rows. If there is text then a corresponding box is filled and colored accordingly, the same applies if data is missing. After the loop is completed it counts a summary of the cells with all data and with missing data an fills this in an overview on Sheet "One".

When the code needs to run for the entire column to check data in, it will do so without problems. However when a filter is selected the code does no start at the filtered selection, instead it starts at the second cell in the column. It does because I defined the second cell as the starting point. I cannot figure out however how to define the starting point in such a dynamic way that it will follow with the filter settings. Furthermore the code does not compensate for "gaps" (e.g. when the filter settings make the row jump from row 5 to row 30, the code will keep counting on from 5, it does not jump along so to speak). As the data sets can number up to around 150.000 a lot of gaps can be present, so this cripples the code heavily.
See my code below.

```
    Sub CompletionStatusUpdate()

    Dim CompletionStatus As Range 'Creates list to check for Completion Status
    Dim DataGetCompletion As Long 'Defines counter to determine maximum list limit to check

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Two").Range("H2:H" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H9").Value).Interior.ColorIndex = 0 'Reset Colors in 2nd Tab for Completion Status
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Two").Range("H2:H" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H9")).Value = "" 'Reset Values in 2nd Tab for Completion Status  
    'Cell H9 in Sheet One contains a CountA function which checks the amount of data present in Sheet Two. Right now it counts the entire amount of data in row C, 
    'however this needs to be adjusted to only count the cells of data which are filtered in row C

    For Each CompletionStatus In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Two").Range("H2:H" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H9").Value + 1) 
    'Creates loop for cells that need to be filled/colored
    'This needs to run over only the filtered cells in the selection
    'Instead of over the H column untill H9 value is reached regardles of filters

    DataGetCompletion = (DataGetCompletion + 1) 'DataGetCompletion Counter for Range, used to move the position of cells to fill in

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H6").Value = DataGetCompletion + 2 'Ticks up for each loop run through, corrected for the starting cell
    'Again this needs adjust dependant on the filter settings

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Two").Range("D" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H9")).Value = "Yes" And _
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Two").Range("F" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H9")).Value = "Yes" Then 
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H8").Value = 1 'Both Data sets are present,used in separate logic
    End If 'This needs to check only filtered cells as well, instead of all cells

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Two").Range("D" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H9")).Value = "No" And _
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Two").Range("F" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H9")).Value = "No" Then 
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H8").Value = 0 'Both data sets missing, used in separate logic
    End If 'This needs to check only filtered cells as well, instead of all cells

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H8") = 0 Then 'Both data sets missing, so problem
       CompletionStatus.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Colors cell red
       CompletionStatus.Value = "Both data sets missing" 'Displays missing information
    End If

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H8") = 1 Then 'Data sets complete
       CompletionStatus.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'Colors cell green
       CompletionStatus.Value = "Both data sets complete" 'Displays completion
    End If

    Next CompletionStatus 'Reruns loop till completion

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H11").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf _
    (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Two").Range("H2:H" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H9").Value + 1), "Both data sets complete")

    'Displays amount of complete data sets 
    'This part of the code also needs to run over the filtered selection in the H column, instead of starting from H2 and running till value Sheet One, H9 is reached

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H13").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf _
    (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Two").Range("H2:H" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("One").Range("H9").Value + 1), "Both data sets missing")

    'Displays amount of missing data sets
    'This part of the code also needs to run over the filtered selection in the H column, instead of starting from H2 and running till value Sheet One, H9 is reached

     End Sub
```

I just cant seem to get it to work with the filters, I've tried different applications of the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` code but it didn't help me.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated, if something is not clear please let me know.

Comment: I think you've narrowed the info too much - I'm not clear on what your question is.  What about the above code isn't working?

Comment: Have you tried using `find` or `match` using `CountIf` with a loop ?

Comment: You are using `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")` and `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview and Filters")` repeatedly. I would suggest to qualify these sheets and use the qualified object. This will make your code a lot more readable and smaller. At the moment I'm struggling to understand your code. Just a suggestion

Comment: @ matt The problem is when I filter the data in the Overview Tab, both the cell coloring code, the yes or no data entrie code and the lines of code that count the completion status options do not work ovet the filtered selection.

Instead they start at the second row of cells and then check down the amount of cells that has been filtered. I want them to only work on the filtered options instead of what they do now.

@ mitch, no I havent. Could you explain a bit further what you mean?

@ Zac i will adjust the code tomorrow afternoon and upload a more comprehensible version.

Comment: You don't use _ after the key word "Then" as it is a natural line break and does not need a line continuation i.e. Then _ should be just Then as you will then be onto the next statement.

Comment: @QHarr thanks for the feedback, adjusted it. However that was not the one causing me most headache ;) Any ideas how to get the main problem solved?

Comment: What do you mean by filter? Is there a filter already applied that is not visible in the above code?

Comment: @QHarr Yeah, like I mentioned, the data sets in Sheet "Two" can be filtered using a drop down menu in the first row of that sheet. If no filter is applied (e.g filter is on "Select All") then the code works. However when I select a filter to apply from the drop down menu the code doesn't adjust accordingly, it keeps working over all present data sets instead of working only over the filtered selection.

Comment: Also can you not  start DataGetCompletion = 3 and get rid of  DataGetCompletion + 2 ?

Comment: @QHarr Yes that would be possible, I may not be the neatest writer when it comes to code. Elegance is not my strong point. However, that's not really the point why I posted this topic.

Comment: I am working my way through your code but wanted to check my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try doing a check on whether the row is visible within the loop range. The principle being, whatever you are looping over, see if the `.EntireRow.Hidden` status of `CompletionStatus` is `False`. If `False` it means it is visible and you want to do your check.

```
 For Each CompletionStatus In loopRange

        If CompletionStatus.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then

            Select Case h8Range

            Case 1 'this was 1 in yours

                CompletionStatus.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                CompletionStatus.Value = "Both data sets complete"

            Case 2 'this was 0 in yours

                CompletionStatus.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                CompletionStatus.Value = "Both data sets missing"

            End Select

        End If

    Next CompletionStatus
```

I re-wrote the entire code, without knowing what your data looks like to something like as follows. I don't expect it to work off the bat for you but shows you a structure. I don't think a lot of the elements were actually doing anything which is why I have removed them. Let's hope not in error. However, the principle at the start for how to solve your problem remains the same.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompletionStatusUpdate()

    Dim CompletionStatus As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("One")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Two")

    Dim h9Range As Range
    Set h9Range = ws1.Range("H9")

    'Test for h9Range being not empty and that is greater than 2?
    ws2.Range("H2:H" & h9Range.Value + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0 'if this is intended to clear prior runs it needs + 1
    ws2.Range("H2:H" & h9Range.Value + 1).ClearContents 'This seems to be the same as loopRange?

    Dim completeRange As Range
    Set completeRange = ws1.Range("H11")

    Dim missingRange As Range
    Set missingRange = ws1.Range("H13")

    missingRange.ClearContents
    completeRange.ClearContents

    Dim h8Range As Range
    Set h8Range = ws1.Range("H8")

    Dim dRange As Range
    Set dRange = ws2.Range("D" & h9Range.Value)

    Dim fRange As Range
    Set fRange = ws2.Range("F" & h9Range.Value)

    Dim countRange As Range
    Set countRange = ws2.Range("H2:H" & h9Range.Value + 1)

    Dim h6Range As Range
    Set h6Range = ws1.Range("H6")

    Dim loopRange As Range

    Set loopRange = ws2.Range("H2:H" & h9Range.Value + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    DataGetCompletion = 3


    If dRange = "Yes" And fRange = "Yes" Then

        h8Range = 1

    ElseIf dRange = "No" And fRange = "No" Then

        h8Range = 2

    Else

        h8Range = 3

    End If


    For Each CompletionStatus In loopRange

        If CompletionStatus.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then

            Select Case h8Range

            Case 1

                CompletionStatus.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                CompletionStatus.Value = "Both data sets complete"

            Case 2

                CompletionStatus.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                CompletionStatus.Value = "Both data sets missing"

            End Select

        End If

    Next CompletionStatus


    completeRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf _
                    (countRange, "Both data sets complete")

    missingRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf _
                   (countRange, "Both data sets missing")

End Sub
```

Comment: Damn, thanks man, that really helped a lot, was able to get the sequencing fine tuned thanks to you. I've got it set up an running over small data sets, getting ready to test it out on the big batches later this week. It works so far and does exactly what I want it to.